# JFrog CLI setting folder properties on upload

Tags: artifactory, jfrog-cli

I need to set folder properties on folder upload.  I can't use `set-props` as it's not available on JFrog Artifactory Open Source. I tried using the JFrog CLI `upload`'s `--target-props` option, but it doesn't work on folder uploads (no properties are set):

```
$ jf rt search "test1/folder1" --include-dirs=true --server-id=ServerID
15:34:32 [Info] Searching artifacts...
15:34:36 [Info] Found 0 artifacts.
[]
$ jf rt upload "folder1" "test1/folder1" -include-dirs=true --quiet=true --server-id=ServerID '--target-props=prop1=a;prop2=b'
15:35:55 [Info] Log path: /home/gdlxn/.jfrog/logs/jfrog-cli.2023-08-28.15-35-55.237357.log
15:35:55 [Info] These files were uploaded:

 test1
└──  folder1

{
  "status": "success",
  "totals": {
    "success": 1,
    "failure": 0
  }
}
$ jf rt search "test1/folder1" --include-dirs=true --server-id=ServerID
15:35:59 [Info] Searching artifacts...
15:35:59 [Info] Found 1 artifact.
[
  {
    "path": "test1/folder1",
    "type": "folder",
    "created": "2023-08-28T19:35:55.436Z",
    "modified": "2023-08-28T19:35:55.436Z"
  }
]
```

I'm using JFrog CLI version 2.46.2 on Ubuntu 20.04 and have seen the problem when uploading to JFrog Artifactory 7.41.7 Open Source.

Is this a JFrog CLI bug?  If not, how can I set folder properties in JFrog Artifactory Open Source.  Note that I need to be able to do this in a Python script, so using the JFrog UI is not an option for me.

Comment: I found that one can report JFrog CLI bugs at JFrog CLI Issues (https://github.com/jfrog/jfrog-cli/issues).  So I opened JFrog CLI Issue #2171 (https://github.com/jfrog/jfrog-cli/issues/2171).